# How to measure size of an expanded combo box (select option)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-selectors, size

When expanding dropdown menu I would like to measure size of the combo box:

```
$("select").on("click", function() {
    $("#log").html($(this).width() + " " + $(this).height());
});
```

This doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/stefek99/JfqJW/

As an experiment I tried to measure size in setTimeout: http://jsfiddle.net/stefek99/PpeK3/

```
$("select").on("click", function() {
    var $that = $(this);
    setTimeout(function(){fnMeasureSize($that)}, 1000); 
});
```

*(and it also doesn't work)*

Difficulty with setting breakpoints / inspecting elements is that combo box is a **canny beast that collapses**. I was also thinking about calculating number of items and multiplying by line-height.

**Is there any recommended way of getting the size?**

*(both jQuery and vanilla JS solutions appreciated)*

Answer (score 0):

Don't think you can. The dropdown part of the list is OS-dependent and it can be quite different depending on the device. For example, on mobile, the dropdown portion is implemented as more of a scrolling selector than an actual fly-out widget.